# Push Notification with a timer - iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios4, push, push-notification

I would like to send a push notification to the user but I want it to appear only for few seconds and not to stay on the screen. Can I set a timer to close the received notification?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can not. The display of push notifications is handled at the system level and unfortunately you don't have any control over them other than to enable or disable them entirely.